# UITableViewCell UIView color not changed immediately when class loaded

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

UIView background color not changed immediately inside `UITableViewCell`,
when class loaded first time `StatusTableViewCell` `(TableViewCell)` appears `backgroundStatusCell (UIView)` with default background color,
Even the `guard` condition executed the background color of `backgroundStatusCell` is not effected.  It happens only when then cell is scrolled.

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StatusTableViewCell") as! StatusTableViewCell
        statusViewModel.configurationStatusCell(cell: cell, forRowAtIndexPath: indexPath as NSIndexPath)

        guard  statusViewModel.progressValues(indexValue: indexPath.row) >= 50 else{

            cell.backgroundStatusView.backgroundColor = .blue
           return cell
        }
        cell.backgroundStatusView.backgroundColor =.red


        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: use guard for unwrapping optional. Don't use it for conditional checks, as it does an early exit.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri unwrapping optional used for check the nil conditon or not!  So why can we use guard for condition ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StatusTableViewCell") as! StatusTableViewCell
        statusViewModel.configurationStatusCell(cell: cell, forRowAtIndexPath: indexPath as NSIndexPath)

        if statusViewModel.progressValues(indexValue: indexPath.row) >= 50
        {
           cell.backgroundStatusView.backgroundColor =.red
           //or
           //cell.backgroundColor =.red
        }
        else{
            cell.backgroundStatusView.backgroundColor = .blue
            //or
           //cell.backgroundColor =.blue
        }
        return cell
```